# Is there a way to quickly know these statements are true without proving them?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

$$\exists y \forall xP(x, y) \equiv \forall x \exists yP(x,y)\tag{1}$$
$$\exists y \forall x(P(x) \lor Q(y)) \equiv \forall x P(x) \lor \exists x Q(x)\tag{2}$$

$$\exists x(P(x) \lor Q(x)) \equiv \exists xP(x)\lor \exists yQ(y)\tag{3}$$

Without proving them is there a way to quickly know whether it is true or not?

Comment: Proof or counterexample is the best way to know if something is true or false.

Answer (score 3):

You can use proof by *counterexample* to rule out (*disprove*) a given equivalence. All you need is *one* counterexample in which the equivalence *fails to hold* to disprove the equivalence.

To do so, try translating the expressions to get a feel for what they are asserting.

If you aren't able to quickly find a counterexample, then you need to try to prove the equivalence; if that proves impossible, you might gain insight into why that is, and then try again to come up with a counterexample.

***But, there's no getting around thoroughly understanding quantifiers and predicates.***
The more you work with exercises like these, the more quickly you'll get at being able to
prove or disprove such statements.

---

Let's work through the first proposed equivalence:

$$\exists y \forall xP(x, y) \equiv \forall x \exists yP(x,y)\tag{1}$$

Let $x, y$ be in the domain of all people. Let $P(x, y)$ denote "$x$ loves $y$". (Counterexample)

Then the left-hand-side translates to: "There is someone whom everyone loves."

The right-hand-side translates to "Everyone loves someone."

Can you see how these are not equivalent statements?

---

For the next two assertions, think of a predicate which we can denote $P(x)$ and one to denote $Q(x)$, where $x$ is in some domain over which we are quantifying, and try translating into words what each statement is stating.

$$\exists y \forall x(P(x) \lor Q(y)) \equiv \forall x P(x) \lor \exists x Q(x)\tag{2}$$

$$\exists x(P(x) \lor Q(x)) \equiv \exists xP(x)\lor \exists yQ(y)\tag{3}$$

---

Recall, also, that $a \equiv b$ denotes "double implication": $(a\rightarrow b) \land (b\rightarrow a)$, which means that to be equivalent, either $a$ and $b$ must both be true, or else they must both be false. If one can be true and the other false, then the $a\not\equiv b$.